# How do you kill all instances of a systemd service?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I want to kill all instances of a systemd service.

This works fine: `sudo systemctl stop 'custom-service@*'`
but it is slow since it runs my custom `ExecStop` which does extra work to safely shut down the process.

In certain cases, I'd rather just kill the processes. I tried to do it this way
`sudo systemctl kill -s SIGKILL 'custom-service@*'` however, this doesn't kill anything.

If I modify this to a specific instance it works fine and the instance gets killed.
e.g. `sudo systemctl kill -s SIGKILL 'custom-service@someinstance-1.service'` but I'd rather not do that for each one.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use systemd stop. In general it's not a good idea sending SIGKILL to any systemd units. Also if you read man systemd.kill it only works on one particular unit at a time, no globs.

Comment: This seems fair, I've gone ahead and switched to just use stop. It's not really what I wanted but it works well enough for my scenario.

Comment: No. This is incomplete, erroneous instruction. "systemd stop" results in "Excess arguments."